# Automatic todo scheduling in emacs org-mode using estimate

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use the fantastic emacs org-mode to manage my todos and also import my calendar into org-agenda. 
Most of my todos have a time estimate in org-mode.

Question 1. Is there a way to have emacs suggest/schedule todos automatically? E.g. look at the open todos, take their time estimate and find a slot to put it in.

Question 2. My todos also have deadlines and schedule dates. Is there a way to make emacs sum up the time estimates of todos with deadlines and mark in my org-agenda a time block indicating that this much time will be taken by the todo?

In general, i would like to use the time estimates and deadlines in a more interesting way to help me plan my tasks.

Many thanks,
Stephan

Comment: The only scheduling solution that I'm aware of is Taskjuggler. Looks like you can export org to TJ: https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/taskjuggler/ox-taskjuggler.html . I never used that myself, though. Make sure your not using the Qt-version of TJ which is outdated.